# When grouping by all columns in a data.table, .SD is empty

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble getting consistent output in `data.table` using consistent syntax. See example below

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = c(1,1,2,2))
# data.table shown below
#  x y
1: 1 1
2: 1 1
3: 2 2
4: 2 2

d[, if(.N>1) .SD else NULL, by = .(x, y)]
# returns Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: x,y
```

When all columns are used for grouping in `by`, `.SD` is empty, causing an empty `data.table` to be returned.

When one adds another column, `.SD` contains columns not being grouped by, the correct output is returned.

```
   d[, if(.N>1) .SD else NULL, by = x]
   # returns
        x y
     1: 1 1
     2: 1 1
     3: 2 2
     4: 2 2
  
  d <- data.table(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = c(1,1,2,2), t = 1:4)
  d[, if(.N>1) .SD else NULL, by = .(x, y)]
  # returns
      x y t
   1: 1 1 1
   2: 1 1 2
   3: 2 2 3
   4: 2 2 4
```

I'm trying to find a way to write code to return rows that appear duplicate times that works for both the case where the by columns do and don't consist of all columns in the data.table. Toward this end, I tried setting `.SDcols = c("x", "y")`. However, the columns get repeated in the output

```
d[, if(.N>1) .SD else NULL, by = .(x, y), .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
    x y x y
 1: 1 1 1 1
 2: 1 1 1 1
 3: 2 2 2 2
 4: 2 2 2 2
```

Is there a way to make it so `d[, if(.N > 1) .SD else NULL, by = colnames]` returns the desired output independent of whether the column names grouped by consist of all columns in 'd'? Or do I need to use an `if` statement and break up the 2 cases?

Comment: `.SD` is an empty data.table if all columns are used in  `by`.

Comment: Here's one way of achieving your objective: `d[,rep(.N>1,.N),by=.(x,y)][(V1)][,V1:=NULL]`. This works for your current case. Alternately, you should set a key, identify the groups to keep and merge.

Comment: Roland comment perfectly described your issue. You can also check [introduction](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html) vignette as there is a `.SD` description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach

```
setkey(d,x,y)
dnew <- d[d[,.N>1,by=key(d)][(V1),key(d),with=FALSE]]
```

This

1. sets `(x,y)` to a key;
2. identifies which `(x,y)` groups satisfy the criterion; and then
3. selects those groups from `d`.

Comment: I chose an if statement approach in the end.