# Using all columns in by with .SD produces empty table?

Tags: r, data.table

One of the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475632/when-grouping-by-all-columns-in-a-data-table-sd-is-empty) says:

> `.SD` is an empty data.table if all columns are used in `by`.

I don't understand the logic behind this? For example:

```
library(data.table)
    dt <- data.table(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = c(1,2,3,3))
    dt
```

```
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 2 3
4: 2 3
```

```
    dt[, .SD[.N], by = .(x, y)]
```

```
Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): x,y
```

It would make more sense to me if the output of the above was the same as the final output of the following code:

```
    dt[, keep := (1:.N) == .N, by = .(x, y)]
    dt[keep == 1, c("x", "y")]
```

```
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 2 3
```

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-sd-usage.html#grouped--sd-operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see what is happening when you do group, try grouping by one variable and `browser()`-ing in the calculation portion. But first, note that `data.table` is smart enough to know before calling the `j=` (calculations/assignment) portion what symbols/columns it is referencing.

For instance, if we do not reference any of the columns, we'll see this when grouping by one variable.

```r
> dt[, { browser(); 1; }, by = .(x)]
Called from: `[.data.table`(dt, , {
    browser()
    1
  ...
Browse[1]> debug at #1: [1] 1
Browse[2]> .SD
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
Browse[2]> Q
```

If we reference `y` or `.SD` (symbols) in the braces, we'll see more:

```r
dt[, { browser(); .SD; }, by = .(x)]
# Called from: `[.data.table`(dt, , {
#     browser()
#     .SD
#   ...
debug at #1: .SD
.SD
#        y
#    <num>
# 1:     1
# 2:     2
```

Let's look at that when we group by both (all) variables:

```r
> dt[, { browser(); .SD; }, by = .(x, y)]
Called from: `[.data.table`(dt, , {
    browser()
    .SD
  ...
Browse[1]> debug at #1: .SD
Browse[2]> .SD
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
Browse[2]> ls(all.names = TRUE)
 [1] "-.POSIXt"  ".BY"       ".GRP"      ".I"        ".iSD"      ".N"        ".NGRP"     ".SD"       ".SDall"    ".xSD"      "Cfastmean" "print"    
[13] "strptime"  "x"         "y"        
Browse[2]> .BY
$x
[1] 1
$y
[1] 1
Browse[2]> x
[1] 1
Browse[2]> y
[1] 1
```

Why is this? the standard `.SD` is generally made of all columns except the grouping variables. Even if we reference them beforehand,

```r
dt[, { browser(); x; y; .SD; }, by = .(x, y)]
```

the `.SD` has 0 rows and we see `x` and `y` as length-1 vectors (values for that instance of `x,y`).

There is an open GH issue raise about this question ([Empty data.table produced with .SD when grouping by all columns](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3262)) posted in Jan 2019, though from the discussion (and lack of action), I don't foresee a change anytime soon.

Similarly, there's a related issue ([Columns appearing in the function in `by=` disappers in j](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1427)) that is also relevant, and in fact I think it is the core "culprit".

We can use the knowledge that columns directly referenced in the `by=` argument are removed to work around it: predefine a grouping vector.
For example, notice the *actual* difference (as opposed to the *practical* difference) between these two blocks:

```r
dt[, .SD[.N,], by = .(grp = interaction(x, y))]
# Empty data.table (0 rows and 1 cols): grp

### and

grp <- dt[, interaction(x, y)]
dt[, .SD[.N,], by = .(grp)]
#       grp     x     y
#    <fctr> <num> <num>
# 1:    1.1     1     1
# 2:    1.2     1     2
# 3:    2.3     2     3
```

where cleanup of that extra column is unambiguous and easy:

```r
dt[, .SD[.N,], by = .(grp)][, grp := NULL][]
#        x     y
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     1     1
# 2:     1     2
# 3:     2     3
```

I agree (and in fact [commented as such](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3262#issuecomment-665115306) over three years ago), but it is what it is.

Bottom line: if you know you're grouping by all columns, or think you *may* and want to guard against it, consider using the (predefined) `grp <- ...` hack above.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I will have to digest it for a while, which is also why it took me some time to mark it as accepted, cheers! :)